# remove duplicates in JSON values using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "function": "ping",
    "name": "start",
    "servers": [
      {
        "load": 581.6875,
        "last_heard": 2.379324197769165,
        "version": "1.0",
        "hidden": false,
        "pid": "19735"
      },
      {
        "load": 444.0625,
        "last_heard": 1.3227169513702393,
        "version": "1.0",
        "hidden": false,
        "pid": "12092"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "function": "pong",
    "name": "middle",
    "servers": [
      {
        "load": 581.6875,
        "last_heard": 2.379324197769165,
        "version": "2.0",
        "hidden": false,
        "pid": "19735"
      },
      {
        "load": 444.0625,
        "last_heard": 1.3227169513702393,
        "version": "3.0",
        "hidden": false,
        "pid": "12092"
      },
      {
        "load": 444.0625,
        "last_heard": 1.3227169513702393,
        "version": "3.0",
        "hidden": false,
        "pid": "12093"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "function": "pang",
    "name": "end",
    "servers": [
      {
        "load": 581.6875,
        "last_heard": 2.379324197769165,
        "version": "2.0",
        "hidden": false,
        "pid": "19735"
      },
      {
        "load": 444.0625,
        "last_heard": 1.3227169513702393,
        "version": "2.0",
        "hidden": false,
        "pid": "12092"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

(it's just a sample, it's hundreds of entries)

What I need is to get

```
[{"name": "start", "version": ["1.0"]},
{"name": "middle", "version": ["2.0", "3.0"]},
{"name": "end", "version": ["2.0"]}]
```

So I need to remove useless data and then get a list of names with their unique values for "version".

I can get until the point where I have

```
{
  "name": "ping",
  "version": [
    "1.0",
    "1.0"
  ]
}
{
  "name": "pong",
  "version": [
    "2.0",
    "3.0",
    "3.0"
  ]
}
{
  "name": "pang",
  "version": [
    "2.0",
    "2.0"
  ]
}
```

using

```
jq '.[] | {name: .function, version: [.servers[].version]}'
```

But I need to get rid of the duplicated values.
Is this possible using jq?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You were almost there. Just pipe the `version` array to the `unique` function:

```
jq '[.[]|{name, "version": [.servers[].version]|unique}]' input
```

Comment: I am pretty sure I've tried this, but with all the tests I've made it probably was wrong somewhere :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses **reduce** to gather version keys in a temporary object and dedup at the end using **keys**

```
 [
   . []
 | reduce .servers[].version as $v (
     {name, version:{}}
   ; .version[$v] = 1
   )
 | .version |= keys
 ]
```