# Bash script - remove duplicate key value pairs from Json

Tags: bash, shell

I got a list of files that I would have to iterate over and read each json as text from a file, see if there are duplicates key value pair and remove the duplicates.

I have written the script to iterate over each file and read line by line, and need help to search for duplicates. I know the duplicates key for now - "user_context and User_Context".

My sample json:

```
{"context_id”:”8fba96a626d2-1234“,”context_1”:”00016”,”User_Context”:”ctx1”,”context_Id":"CountRows”,”date":"2020-08-17”,”user_context”:”ctx1”,"name":"n1"}
```

JSON is big and i have removed many keys for testing. And there are also many files.

Tried the below jq command:

jq -c -M 'del(.user_context)' ${str1} > tmp

inside #!/bin/bash script and get "jq: command not found"

Any help please.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove duplicates in JSON values using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766735/remove-duplicates-in-json-values-using-jq)

Comment: jq: command not found inside bash script

Comment: Using bash script and its QA environment server. So I don't have permission to install.

Comment: Is there other way to search for duplicates and remove?

Comment: `jq` is the typical command for processing JSON in shell scripts. If you can't install that, consider instead using something like python/node.js//ruby/perl/whatever that has native support for reading JSON data. Note that you could probably install `jq` into a local directory and it would work just fine.

Comment: So install `jq`?

Comment: yes, finally used Jp to check for duplicates

Comment: What software _is_ installed? It's rare not to have Python, and that has a perfectly good JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

Installed Jp and used to remove duplicates

Comment: Do you intend to extend this into an answer showing _how_ you did this with `jp`? (My first thought would be to close the question as a duplicate, but since you're discussing jp and the other one uses jq, there may be room for both; would want to extend the title to clarify exactly what that difference is).